# Mysql storage to perform search on integer or text

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an app that stores product information i.e. name, category, price etc.

A product can belong to multiple categories so there will be a category table to hold this information against a product however I would like to allow users the ability to search for products on whatever word they like. What I mean is a user could enter a product name, something in the description, a category, price etc. Entirely up to the user.

The query I am guessing (as it is not built yet) would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product 
JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_product.product_id = tbl_category.product_id
WHERE
    tbl_product.name LIKE $query
    OR tbl_product.description LIKE $query
    OR tbl_category.category etc.
```

I was wondering what the best way to store this data would be because I also have a column in the product table which is product type which is currently an integer(1 = top, 2 = bottom, 3 = shoes etc) however users searching for top won't enter 1 in the search, they will enter top or tops. I know it is quicker to search based on integer but would it be quicker to store 'top' in the product table to search on or store '1' and do a join?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option - and I'm not saying this is the best option, but it could work for you - is to collect a keyword column on your products that store the primary search fields as a single text entry.

When you create or update a product, you rebuild this string and perform a single match against on that column.

So say you have a product like this:

title: Cool tool
body: A socket wrench with a built in lightsaber
tags: tools, lightsaber, cool (these would be relational like the category, but just for example I list them as strings here)

And it is in the category `Tools`, as well as the category `Camping`.

On save (add or edit) you compose a string that is a collection of all the text itself:

"Cool tool A socket wrench with a built in 

lightsaber tools lightsaber cool tools camping"

even if it is redundant.

Then you search like:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE MATCH(`search_terms`) AGAINST({search_term} IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So you don't have to worry about cross table where clauses.
You may need to familiarize yourself with [match against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en//fulltext-search.html) but there are plenty of resources out there for that.

I've done this before and it worked very well for me. Never had any performance issues.